# Empty table of content, list of figures, list of tables

Tags: table-of-contents, lncs

The table of content, list of figures, list of tables all shows nothing!

Hello there, please help with this issue. I've compiled more than twice. There shows no error. My code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{llncs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{bbm}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage{exscale,latexsym}
\usepackage{epic}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage[flushmargin]{footmisc}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage[small]{caption}
\usepackage{graphpap}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\usepackage[a4paper, lmargin=6cm, rmargin = 2cm, tmargin = 3cm, bmargin = 3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\usepackage{fancyref}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}           
\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents

\newpage
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures\vspace{0pt}}
\listoffigures

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Tables\vspace{0pt}}
\listoftables

\newpage
\section{Table of Abbreviations}   
\section{Table of Symbols} 

\end{document}
```

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please complete your code to a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that   starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`. Do you compile twice?

Comment: Off-topic: As you're already loading the `amssymb` package, there can be no justification for loading the deprecated `latexsym` package as well. And, since you're loading the `graphicx` package, there can be no justification for loading the `epsfig` package. Next, since you load the `setspace` package and execute `\onehalfspacing`, running `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}` can only be counterproductive. Finally, don't load packages more than once.

Comment: thank you!! I didn't notice since I've just copy-paste from the template and during writing added some packages again. But why are they empty??

Comment: @GwenYang: *Never* use templates, they are most times rubbish. The main reason you don't see entries in the ToC is the fact that `tocdepth` is 0 by default in `llncs`. See my answer below for more explanations

Comment: One side -note: There **is** a reason that `llncs` has `\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}` -- Springer journals/books guidelines apparently demand that structure levels below chapter should not appear in the ToC. So if this should be a submission to Springer, changing `tocdepth` will be rejected, eventually (Don't ask me why Springer designed it this way, however)

Answer (score 3):

By default, `llncs` `tocdepth` value is `0`, so only chapters and parts are shown in the ToC, but no sections and deeper levels of structure.

If `\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}` is used, the sections show up in the ToC.

I suggest to use `\usepackage{tocbibind}` in order to add the `LoF` and `LoT` in the `ToC` as well, if the `ToC` should not be listed itself, use `\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}` instead.

As long as no `figure` or `table` environments with `\caption` commands or explicit `\addcontentsline{lof}{...}{...}` etc. are used, the `LoF` and `LoT` are empty of course.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{llncs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{bbm}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage{exscale}
\usepackage{epic}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage[flushmargin]{footmisc}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage[small]{caption}
\usepackage{graphpap}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage[dvips]{epsfig}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage[a4paper, lmargin=6cm, rmargin = 2cm, tmargin = 3cm, bmargin = 3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
% 
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\usepackage{fancyref}

\usepackage{tocbibind}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}           
\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{Roman}
%\setcounter{page}{1}% Pagenumbering sets the page counter always to 1

%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures\vspace{0pt}}
\listoffigures

%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Tables\vspace{0pt}}
\listoftables

\clearpage
\section{Table of Abbreviations}   
\section{Table of Symbols} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `LoF` and `LoT` are empty because there are no figures nor tables with `\caption` commands in your code

Comment: you are correct!! Thank you so much. But how do I get deeper levels after section shown in the table of content??

Comment: `\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}` gives you all down to `\paragraph` ... the higher the tocdepth value, the deeper the structure level show up in the `ToC`

Comment: It's working perfectly!! Thank you angel :)

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `\section` not `\section*` to get them in toc. If you don't want numbering on some particular sections then you can use something like `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}` for those. Working example (Edit: Turns out `llncs` class has some weird behavior, I added `\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}` to preamble and it worked.)

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\begin{document}    
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage

    % this section doesn't have numbering
    %\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
    \section{Table of Abbreviations} 

    % this section has numbering
    %\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
    \section{Table of Symbols} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: hello thank you for the answer. But I have more content in the document that i didn't show. There are \section{}. And I've tried \setcounter{secnumdepth}{1} just now and still empty. Also the list of tables and list of figures are empty. why???

Comment: I tried the example that you provided and it works with my fix (`\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}` is an example, you can increase it if you want). If you are still facing the issue then could you construct a simple example (remove unnecessary packages and formatting as Mico suggested). I will check if I missed anything.

Comment: Edited. The behavior was peculiar to `llncs` class which I missed before.

Comment: thank you. I've removed unnecessary packages. Now after adding the packages suggested above it's working.

Comment: Also, reiterating an important point which Christian Hupfer has mentioned  in comments. If you are submitting your work to a place which requires you to stick to a specific template then you should check with them before making any changes.

Comment: Thank you for the tips guys. This is my first paper using LaTex. I'll get better next time :)